# flip effect Fragment transaction with getSupportFragmentManger

Tags: android, android-fragments, animation

> flip_left_in.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
        android:fromXDelta="90%p"
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/decelerate_quint"
        android:toXDelta="0%p"/>

    <alpha
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/decelerate_quint"
        android:toAlpha="1.0"/>
</set>
```

> flip_left_out.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
        android:fromXDelta="0%p"
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/decelerate_quint"
        android:toXDelta="-90%p" />

    <alpha
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/decelerate_quint"
        android:toAlpha="0.0" />
</set>
```

> flip_right_in.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
        android:fromXDelta="-100%p"
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/decelerate_quint"
        android:toXDelta="0%p" />

    <alpha
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/decelerate_quint"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" />
</set>
```

> flip_right_out.xml

```
<translate
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
    android:fromXDelta="0%p"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/decelerate_quint"
    android:toXDelta="100%p" />

<alpha
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
    android:fromAlpha="1.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/decelerate_quint"
    android:toAlpha="0.0" />
```

I have got the above four xml's in my anim folder to create 3d flip efect.

Im using getSupportFragmentManager and hence I cant use object animator.

I have set the custom animation by referring the above anim files while performing the fragment transaction as follows,

```
 fm.beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.anim.flip_right_in, R.anim.flip_right_out,
                    R.anim.flip_left_in, R.anim.flip_left_out)
                    .add(R.id.replace, newFragment, "folderContent")
                    .show(newFragment)
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

The problem is that the 3d flip transation is not happening with the above code. How can i be able to create 3d flip transition during fragment transaction with getSupportFragmentManager?

Comment: Try removing the `show()` call on the `FragmentTransaction`. It's unnecessary, and might be interfering with the animation.

Comment: i tried it but still the same issue is persisting

Comment: Wait, what is the problem, exactly? Are the animations not working at all, or are they just not working as you expect?

Comment: animation is not working as im expecting it to be

Comment: Ah, OK, well those animations are just going to slide and fade. I don't see anything in them to create a 3D effect.

Comment: How can i be able to 3d flip it?

Comment: I have tried setting 0 to -90 and 90 to 0 but still it is not working :(

Comment: Oop, I just had a look in that sample project. It's not using support `Fragment`s. My bad.